# Add Description Column in query from product list table

Tags: ms-access

I'm a beginner to access and I made a database where I currently have two tables:

1. Product list table that has 3 columns: ProductID, Description, Description2
2. A scan table where the user will use a barcode scanner and scan the barcode into the table. It only has 2 columns: ID, and Barcode

I have a query where the first column is the raw barcode and the second is a mid function expression(?) where I extract the information such as product code ( I will add different columns, later, extracting weight, pack date, serial) from the barcode.

Currently, I would like for the the third column to show the Description and Description fields from the product list table. In excel I can do a vlookup, and I have been reading up on Dlookup, but I was wondering if there is an easier alternative to Dlookup because I can't get it to work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let us say that the query to extract product code is:

```
SELECT Barcode, Mid(Barcode,6,3) As ProductID FROM Barcodes
```

It is possible that you have an number data type for ProductID in the Products table, in which case you will have to ensure you have a number data type in the query, you can do this like so:

```
SELECT Barcode, CLng(Mid(Barcode,6,3)) As ProductID FROM Barcodes
```

You can either add this saved query to the Query Design Window along with you Product table and drag the ProductID field from one table to the other to create a join:

[image: query design window]

Or you can build a query using SQL view of the Query Design Window:

```
SELECT q.Barcode, Products.ProductID, Products.Description
FROM (
   SELECT Barcode, Mid(Barcode,6,3) As ProductID 
   FROM Barcodes) As q
INNER JOIN Products
ON q.ProductID = Products.ProductID
```

Of course with the second option, you will have to get everything right for your set up.